# How can I check a Material Checkbox in Angular with a single click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

**Execution:**

I have several Material Checkboxes in a Material Dialog Component. They represent a column filter for a table:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Filter</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of allColumns; index as i; first as firstEntry ">
    <mat-checkbox *ngIf="!firstEntry" class="checkbox" [checked]="checkedList[i]" [aria-label]="column" (click)=doToggle(i)>{{column}}</mat-checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Abbrechen</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="allColumns" cdkFocusInitial>Reset</button>
  <button id="ok-button" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="displayedColumns" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

When I click on a Checkbox I want to check it. All booleans of the Checkboxes are saved in a boolean array named checkedList. When I click on a Checkbox the method doToggle(i) gets executed.

```
doToggle(i: number){
    if(this.checkedList[i]){
      this.displayedColumns[i] = this.allColumns[i];
    }
    else{
      this.displayedColumns[i] = null;
    }
    this.checkedList[i] = !this.checkedList[i];
  }
```

The method also fills or empties the values at the appropriate position of the column list. At the end of the method it negates the boolean at the appropriate position in the checkedList.

**Problem:**
I always have to click twice on the Checkbox to check or uncheck it. The values are added or removed properly. But still I have to click two times on the checkbox. Why is that?

Comment: It's because your checkboxes aren't actually bound to their values - they're only bound using square bindings and will not update with their values initially. I suggest you should use [Angular Forms](http://angular.io/guide/forms) with the `ngModel` attribute.

Comment: ``At the end of the method it negates the boolean at the appropriate position in the checkedList``. why do you have to do this?

Comment: @Supercool. Because otherwise the checkbox wouldnt toggle. The data binding is at a certain position of the checkedList. If the position was true, make if false after clicking on it (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the value of checkbox in the click event.
Add template reference variable(#ck) to checkbox and get its value `ck.checked`

```
[checked]="checkedList[i]" [aria-label]="column" #ck (click)="doToggle(i,!ck.checked)"
```

and in doToggle function

```
doToggle(i,value){
    this.checkedList[i] = value;
    if(this.checkedList[i]){
      this.displayedColumns[i] = this.allColumns[i];
    }
    else{
      this.displayedColumns[i] = null;
    }
  }
```